# Dbus service started as root not accessible to other users

Tags: root, dbus

I have a dbus server publishing some methods started as root.

When I try to access it with a small python client I can't access it until I start the client as root too.

How can I have access as system user to the D-Bus service started as root ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I asked this question due to a lack of experience and knowledge of D-Bus.

In my case I was using the SessionBus to publish my methods. As the name suggest it's a session related bus.
Basically if I start the D-Bus service with my session (my user) then my user can access it.

What I need in my case is to use the SystemBus.

From documentation (http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#introduction):

> D-Bus is designed for two specific use cases:
>
> - A "system bus" for notifications from the system to user sessions, and to allow the system to request input from user sessions.
> - A "session bus" used to implement desktop environments such as GNOME and KDE.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I'm fighting against the .conf files in /etc/dbus-1/system.d but the documentation is the worst thing ever I had read:
http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-daemon.1.html

I think that your problem can be solved configuring your bus. Right now I have that config file:

```
    <policy context="default">
            <allow send_interface="org.company.mybus"/>
            <allow receive_interface="org.company.mybus"
                   receive_sender="org.company.mybus"/>
    </policy>
```

With that I can instance the bus but when I call the exported method **initial_sync_data**, that exceptions appears:

```
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: 
    Rejected send message, 3 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.254"     (uid=100108 pid=5632 comm="python applet_quota.py ") interface="(unset)" member="initial_sync_data" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.253" (uid=0 pid=5603 comm="python main.py ")
```